# I am Trying to send a Discord DM with Python to Multiple Users with Using thier ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am Basicly trying to write !dm Userid1 Userid2 ... Useridn message.
And i Started with that

```
@bot.command()
async def DM(ctx, user1: discord.User, user2: discord.User, *, message=None):
    message = message or "This Message is sent via DM"
    await bot.send_message(user, message)
```

and get the Error User is not defined but if I only use 1 User it will work and i get no Error.
Any Suggestions on what i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
@bot.command()
async def DM(ctx, message, *users: discord.User):
    for user in users:
        await user.send(message)
```

Comment: i get the Error user1ID is not Defined

Comment: Nope ^^ First i got the Error Bot has no Attribute send_message i tried to solve that that with replacing : `bot.send_message`with `ctx.send`. But then i get the Error :  send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I used the wrong command, this should work now